# Getting Update of resource type is not permitted error while updating cloudformation stack of a elasticsearch service to opensearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I've upgraded my elasticsearch domain to opensearch manually through AWS Console. Now I want to update my cloudformation stack. I've also followed official AWS blog for this but still getting same error.

Error: Update of resource type is not permitted. The new template modifies resource type of the following resources: [ElasticSearchDomain]

Comment: did you follow specifically the CF guide (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-opensearchservice-domain.html#aws-resource-opensearchservice-domain--remarks), or just the manual upgrade one? The error sounds like you are trying to update the old stack, not import the domain into the new stack. Note that when you upload the new template, the new stack needs a name that is different from the old one. If that's not it, maybe add the old and new CF templates to the question - hard to troubleshoot without...